# Bash command not executing via .net core Process

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have wrote simple command to do a basic echo on Linux.

This is command I want to do:

```
/bin/bash -c 'echo hello'
```

This is app I am running:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ProcessTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"/bin/bash",
                Arguments = @"-c 'echo hello'",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            };

            using (var process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo })
            {
                process.Start();
                string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                process.WaitForExit();

                Console.WriteLine(result);

                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of outputting "hello" it outputs this:

```
hello': -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
hello': -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: Dunno if this is of any help for you, but it works for me! (I pasted your code into MonoDevelop and executed it on my Ubuntu 18.04 system - did you meant to execute it on Windows?)

Comment: No, I want to execute it on Ubuntu 18.04.  I am using .net core 2.1.  What version of .net are you using?

Comment: Are the single quote characters _exactly_ the same as each other (neither are backticks, for example)?

Comment: @Guerrilla: I am sure, this is the source of the problem - it uses Mono 4.6.2 here. So maybe .net core makes s. th. with the tick characters.

Comment: both single quotes are definitely the same.  I wonder if it could be an encoding issue perhaps?

Comment: It works with double quotes, but seems not to like single quotes

Comment: You already found the answer (to use double quotes), so post it below and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using double quotes works.  For some reason it is just single quotes that cause this issue.

Comment: What is the purpose of this comment?  Stackoverflow has a timer for when you can self mark complete.  As the self appointed SO police I assume you already know this?

Comment: sorry I didn't know ... my apologizes

Answer (score 0):

Use double quote instead of single quote while setting Arguments field.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"/bin/bash",
        Arguments = @"-c ""echo hello""",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    };

    using (var process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo })
    {
        process.Start();
        string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();

        Console.WriteLine(result);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: please note that "Try this" is not an answer, please elaborate and add some description for your answer